# Конвертировать "drawable ID" в путь внутри APK, используя Python

Tags: android, python

Я распарсил AndroidManifest.xml, используя [AndroidXMLPrinter](https://github.com/tracer0tong/axmlprinter) и получил XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<manifest android:allowClearUserData="true" android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="4.0" package="com.fsoft.vktest" platformBuildVersionCode="7" platformBuildVersionName="2.1-update1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE">
</uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
</uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK">
</uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
</uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="21">
</uses-sdk>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@7F020000" android:label="@7F050000">
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
</action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
</category>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:icon="@7F020000" android:label="@7F050000" android:launchMode="1" android:name=".windows.TabsActivity" android:screenOrientation="5">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
</action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
</category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".BotService">
</service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Версия и имя пакета -- обычный текст.

**Но я хочу получить также имя приложения и иконку:**

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@7F020000" android:label="@7F050000">
```

**Как расшифровать значения, начинающиеся с "@"**?

Пока юзаю AAPT, но это не лучшее решение.